# SQL Loader, Trigger saturation?

Tags: performance, oracle, triggers, sql-loader

I have a situation i can't find an explanation for, here it is.  (I'll use hypothetical info since the original are really big.)

I have a table, let's say:

```
table_a
-------------
name
last name
dept
status
notes
```

And this table has a trigger on insert, which does a lot of validation to the info to change the status field of the new record according to the results of the validation, some of the validations are:

```
- check for the name existing in a dictionary
- check for the last name existing in a dictionary
- check that fields (name,last name,dept) aren't already inserted in table_b
- ... and so on
```

The thing is, if I do an insert on the table via query, like

```
insert into table_a 
(name,last_name,dept,status,notes) 
values
('john','smith',1,0,'new');
```

it takes only 173 ms to do all the validation process, update the status field and insert the record in the table. (the validation process does all the searches via indexes)

But if I try this via SQLloader, reading a file with 5000 records, it takes  like 40 minutes to validate and insert 149 records (of course i killed it...)

So I tried loading the data disabling the trigger (to check speed)
and I got that it loads like all the records in less than 10 seconds.

So my question is, what can I do to improve this process? My only theory is that I could be saturating the database because it loads so fast and launches many instances of the trigger, but I really don't know.

My objective is to load around 60 files with info and validate them through the process in the trigger (willing to try other options though).

I would really appreciatte any help you can provide!!

**COMPLEMENT-**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thanks for the answer, now i'll read all about this, now hope you can help me with this part. let me explain some of the functionality i need (and i used a trigger cause i couldn't think of anything else)

so the table data comes with this (important) fields:

```
pid name lastname birthdate dept cicle notes
```

the data comes like this

```
name lastname birthdate dept
```

now, the trigger does this to the data:

1. Calls a function to calculate the pid (is calculated based on the name, lastname and birthdate with an algorithm)
2. Calls a function to check for the names on the dictionary (thats because in my dictionary i have single names, meaning if a person is named john aaron smith jones the function splits john aaron in two, and searches for john and aaron in the dictionary  in separate querys, thats why i didn't use a foreign key [to avoid having lots of combinations john aaron,john alan,john pierce..etc]) --->kinda stuck on how to implement this one with keys without changing the dictionary...maybe with a CHECK?, the lastname foreign key would be good idea.
3. Gets the cicle from another table according to the dept and the current date (because a person can appear twice in the table in the same dept but in different cicle) --->how could i get this cicle value in a more efficient way to do the correct search?
4. And finally, after all this validation is done, i need to know exactly which validation wasn't met (thus the field notes) so the trigger concatenates all the strings of failed validations, like this:

   `lastname not in dictionary, cannot calculate pid (invalid date), name not in dictionary`

i know that if the constraint check isn't met all i could do is insert the record in another table with the constraint-failed error message, but that only leaves me with one validation, am  i right? but i need to validate all of them and send the report to other department so they can review the data and make all the necessary adjustments to it.

Anyway, this is my situation right now, i'll explore possibilities and hope you can share some light on the overall process, Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: For `name` and `last_name`, instead of using a trigger, have you considered foreign key constraints that reference the table (assuming there is one) that represents your dictionary?  For the third validation, did you mean `table_a` or `table_b`?  If you meant `table_a` have you considered a unique constraint instead?  If you meant `table_b` you might consider using a single table instead (or in addition) so that you can use a unique constraint to enforce uniqueness -- it's surprisingly difficult to write a trigger to do this correctly under concurrent inserts/updates (you need to use locking).

Comment: How big is your dictionary?  Check out the stats on the Namex site http://www.namethesaurus.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're halfway to the solution already:

> "So I tried loading the data disabling the trigger (to check speed) ... it loads like all the records in less than 10 seconds."

This is not a surprise.  Your current implementation executes a lot of single row SELECT statements for each row you insert into table B.  That will inevitably give you a poor performance profile.  SQL is a set-based language and performs better with multi-row operations.

So, what you need to do is find a way to replace all the SELECT statements which more efficient alternatives.  Then you'll be able to drop the triggers permanently. For instance, replace the look-ups on the dictionary with foreign keys between the table A columns and the reference table.  Relational integrity constraints, being internal Oracle code, perform much better than any code we can write (and work in multi-user environments too).

The rule about not inserting into table A if a combination of columns already exists in table B is more problematic.  Not because it's hard to do but because it sounds like poor relational design.  If you don't want to load records in table A when they already exits in table B why aren't you loading into table B directly?  Or perhaps you have a sub-set of columns which should be extracted from table A *and* table B and formed into table C (which would have foreign key relationships with A and B)?

Anyway, leaving that to one side, you can do this with set-based SQL by replacing SQL*Loader with an external table.  An external table allows us to present a CSV file to the database as if it were a regular table.  This means we can use it in normal SQL statements.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm#SUTIL011)

So, with foreign key constraints on dictionary and an external table you can replace teh SQL Loader code with this statement (subject to whatever other rules are subsumed into "...and so on"):

```
insert into table_a
select ext.* 
from external_table ext
     left outer join table_b b
     on (ext.name = b.name and ext.last_name = b.last_name and ext.dept=b.dept)
where b.name is null
log errors into err_table_a ('load_fail') ;
```

This employs the DML error logging syntax to capture constraint errors for all rows in a set-based fashion.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#BGBDIGAH).  It won't raise exceptions for rows which already exist in table B.  You could either use [the multi-table INSERT ALL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#i2121682) to route rows into an overflow table or use a MINUS set operation after the event to find rows in the external table which aren't in table A.  Depends on your end goal and how you need to report things.

Perhaps a more complex answer than you were expecting.  Oracle SQL is a very extensive SQL implementation, with a lot of functionality for improving the efficient of bulk operations.  It really pays us to read the Concepts Guide and the SQL Reference to find out just how much we can do with Oracle.

Comment: Thank you very much, now i expanded the info, hope you can review it and give me some tips, Thanks!